# matlab's imfill function seems bugged?

Tags: matlab

I need to work with `imfill` in Matlab (Version 2010b, 7.11.0). I now think there is a bug in the program.
The most simple example that i found [here](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/images/morph13.html) is following: (Fills the Image background (0) beginning at the position `[4 3]`)

```
BW = [ 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0;
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0;
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0;
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0;
       0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0];
imfill(BW,[4 3])
```

According to the specifications this should work IMHO, but I always get following message. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    ??? Error using ==> iptcheckconn at 56
Function IMFILL expected its second input argument, CONN,
to be a valid connectivity specifier.
A nonscalar connectivity specifier must be 3-by-3-by- ...
-by-3.

Error in ==> imfill>parse_inputs at 259
    iptcheckconn(conn, mfilename, 'CONN', conn_position);

Error in ==> imfill at 124
[I,locations,conn,do_fillholes] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in ==> test at 9
imfill(BW,[4 3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not explain the problem but converting BW to a logical array does work. I'm not sure as to why it's like this though:

```
clear
close all
clc

BW = [ 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
       0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0];

BW2 = imfill(logical(BW),[4 3])

BW2 =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Interesting I didn't even try that! Works indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it! Even tough I still do not know whats wrong here=)

Comment: You're welcome! That's still bugging me haha but at least your problem is solved for now :)

Answer (score 2):

As you have already seen in the other solution by @Benoit_11, that most probably that input wasn't of `logical` class, which was throwing an error at you. So, you are set there!

Now, I would like to put forth a tiny bit of bonus suggestion here.

Let's suppose you have a set of seed points with their `row` and `column` IDs and you would like to fill an image with those seed points in one go. For that case,
you need to use those IDs as column vectors. Thus, if you have the `row` and `column` IDs as -

```
row_id = [4 3];
col_id = [3 7];
```

You can fill image with this -

```
BW = imfill(BW,[row_id(:) col_id(:)])
```

But, the following code would throw error at you -

```
BW = imfill(BW,[row_id col_id])
```